# Capitalize title selectively

Tags: php, html, css

I have a list of headings entered like below:

```
junior suite for sale
Beautiful eCommerce office
d'Landon Property for rent
stunning House FOR SALE
```

To make things consistent, we apply `text-transform: capitalize` to the titles, so that the front-end view would be consistent:

```
Junior Suite For Sale
Beautiful ECommerce Office
D'Landon Property For Rent
Stunning House For Sale
```

However, this results in some incorrect names like `eCommerce`, `d'Landon`, which is not desirable. Is there anyway to fix this, hopefully without relying on backend logic change (I use PHP by the way)?

Expected result:

```
Junior Suite For Sale
Beautiful eCommerce Office
d'Landon Property For Rent
Stunning House For Sale
```

Comment: Use regex `/\b(\w)[a-z]/` with callback

Comment: CSS alone can not do that. You will have to modify the HTML in some way or other.

Comment: is javascript an option? I don't think there is a way to do it with CSS.

Comment: _“I have a list of headings entered like below”_ - personally, I’d go slap the people who enter data like that to begin with here :-)

Comment: I can't think of any logic that can determine the *intent* of the writer. How is any code logic supposed to determine that "eCommerce" and "d'Landon" are correct or otherwise?

Comment: Quite simply, you either accept the way it's entered or, more simply, just convert it all to UPPERCASE. They're headings anyway so it wouldn't look that strange that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in `CSS` alone, but in case javascript is an option as mentioned in my comment, here is a snippet:

```js
let pList = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
let blackList = /eCommerce|d'Landon/g

for(let i=0; i< pList.length; i++) {
  let text = pList[i].textContent;
  let newText = text.replace(blackList, '<span class="no-cap">$&<span>');
  pList[i].innerHTML = newText;
}
```

```css
h2 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.no-cap {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>junior suite for sale</h2>
<h2>Beautiful eCommerce office</h2>
<h2>d'Landon Property for rent</h2>
<h2>stunning House FOR SALE</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in PHP. I would write a bunch of regular expressions to figure out which ones are not the way I want. Then replace the ones I don't want with uppercase and lowercase.

Here for example, in the code below, if all the letters are capital in a word, it is converted. If there are any small letters after the first letter in a word, it isn't converted.

```
<?php
$titles = ["junior suite for sale",
"Beautiful eCommerce office",
"d'Landon Property for rent",
"stunning House FOR SALE"];

function smart_title($title){
    $newtitle = [];
    foreach(preg_split("/ /", $title) as $word){
        if(preg_match("/^[A-Z]+$/", substr($word, 1, strlen($word)))){
            array_push($newtitle, strtoupper(substr($word, 0, 1)).strtolower(substr($word, 1, strlen($word))));
        }else if(preg_match("/[A-Z]/", substr($word, 1, strlen($word)))){
            array_push($newtitle, $word);
        }else{
            array_push($newtitle, strtoupper(substr($word, 0, 1)).strtolower(substr($word, 1, strlen($word))));
        }
    }
    return join(" ", $newtitle);
}

foreach($titles as $title){
   echo smart_title($title)."\n";
}
?>
```

Try it out here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/450141f600bb5497b46e48b4f96738e811cd3617 .

Result is:

```
Junior Suite For Sale
Beautiful eCommerce Office
d'Landon Property For Rent
Stunning House For Sale
```